# HTML5 Canvas animation not showing up

Tags: javascript, html, animation, canvas

I've been knocking my head against the keyboard trying to figure out why the animation from [this tutorial](http://www.williammalone.com/articles/create-html5-canvas-javascript-sprite-animation/) is not showing up on the canvas correctly, if at all.  In chrome it draws the leftmost part of the image on the canvas, but in safari it draws nothing at all.

I've tried different methods of delaying until the image loads, putting the script tag in various places in the html, no luck.  Debugging in chrome shows no errors.

The source code for the animation is not quite the same as what he presents in the tutorial, I've tried to make sense of it.  I've been at it for two days and you'll pinpoint it 30 seconds, I want to see this damn coin spin.

spriteSheet.jpg:

[image: spriteSheet.jpg]

animation.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
<title>Test Profile Page</title>
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <h1>Hello</h1>
    </header>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html">Pictures</a></li>
            <li><a href="animation.html">Animation?</a></li>
            <li><a href="cartoon.html">Cartoon</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <section>
        <img src="spriteSheet.jpg" />
        <canvas id="coinAnimation"></canvas>    
    </section>
    <footer>

    </footer>
    <script src="animation.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

animation.js:

```
window.onload = function () {

var spriteSheet = new Image();
spriteSheet.src = "spriteSheet.jpg";

//define sprite class

function sprite (options) {

    var that = {},
        frameIndex = 0,
        tickCount = 0,
        ticksPerFrame = options.ticksPerFrame || 0,
        numberOfFrames = options.numberOfFrames || 1;

    that.context = options.context;
    that.width = options.width;
    that.height = options.height;
    that.image = options.image;
    that.loop = options.loop;

    that.update = function () {

        tickCount += 1;

        if (tickCount > ticksPerFrame) {

          tickCount = 0;

          // If the current frame index is in range
          if (frameIndex < numberOfFrames - 1) {    
            // Go to the next frame
            frameIndex += 1;
          } else if (that.loop) {
            frameIndex = 0;
          }
       }
    };

    that.render = function () {

      // Clear the canvas
      that.context.clearRect(0, 0, that.width, that.height);

      // Draw the animation
      that.context.drawImage(
        that.image,
        frameIndex * that.width / numberOfFrames,
        0,
        that.width / numberOfFrames,
        that.height,
        0,
        0,
        that.width / numberOfFrames,
        that.height);
    };

    return that;

}

var canvas = document.getElementById("coinAnimation");
canvas.width = 100;
canvas.height = 100;

var coin = new sprite({
        context: canvas.getContext("2d"),
        width: 100,
        height: 100,
        image: spriteSheet
});

function gameLoop () {

  window.requestAnimationFrame(gameLoop);

  coin.update();
  coin.render();
}

spriteSheet.addEventListener("load", gameLoop);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you enter the width on your coin you need to enter the width of your entire image (which seems to be `440`), not the width of a single frame. Along with that you need to set the `numberOfFrames` to 10:

```
var coin = new sprite({
        context: canvas.getContext("2d"),
        width: 440, 
        height: 100,
        image: spriteSheet,
        numberOfFrames: 10
});
```

Note when it find the width of a single frame it does `width/numberOfFrames` to find that, this is why it will not work if you just enter `100`. Now your coin should be spinning.

[**Fiddle Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/ps4rdtzL/).

If you want the slow the coin down you can add `ticksPerFrame: 5` for example, the higher that is the slower it will go.

Comment: Great, thank you.  Somehow this info is not in the tutorial, I guess I was supposed to infer it.